# Inheritance in hibernate where derived class has no associated table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am writing entities for an application which needs to represent reports, all these reports has some common fields like; name of the report, period etc. all of these reports contain tables which has different columns(you may consider this as a representation in excel sheet). So far I have designed my database tables where the common fields for all the reports will be stored in a parent table, and for each report there will be another table of multiple tables which will store the data specific to each report. On the database side this design works fine for me.
While creating entities for hibernate, I want to create a parent Report class which will contain the common fields. This Report class must be inherited by all the specific report classes and some more fields will be defined in the derived class which will be specific to each report. These fields will map to the columns in the child table.
I looked into single table inheritance, but the problem is that i can not define any delimiter, also  @MappedSuperclass does not seem to a solution here as my parent class needs to map to a table.

Entity classes must look like following;

```
public class Report // maps to parent table
{
  private Integer reportId;
  private String reportName;
}

public class ReportAData // maps to child table
{
  private Date column1;
  private String column2;
}

public class ReportA extends Report // does not map to any table
{
  private list<ReportARecord> records;
}
```

Can anyone please suggest how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

`TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance strategy sounds like what you want. Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.java2blog.com/2013/02/hibernate-inheritancetable-per-concrete.html) for an example.

Basically, you'll have one table for `Report`, and a table for each subclass which would have a foreign key to `Report` table and all other specific data.

Comment: But i dont have any table for subclass, the purpose for creating subclass is only because each subclass has some different type of composition object which is generally a list.

Comment: You wrote `where the common fields for all the reports will be stored in a parent table, and for each report there will be another table of multiple tables which will store the data specific to each report`, from that I understood you have a table for each report type.

Comment: Also, can you explain what you meant by `the problem is that i can not define any delimiter`?

Answer (score 0):

I managed it using @Entity even with the class with no table :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Report // maps to parent table
{
  private Integer reportId;
  private String reportName;
}

@Entity
public class ReportA extends Report // does not map to any table
{
  private list<ReportARecord> records;
}
```